# Как правильно оформить пунктуацию в данном случае при словах автора?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь

Есть правило, что если слова автора, идущие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, не связанное с употребленной ранее прямой речью, то они пишутся с большой буквы.

Пример из Розенталя:
"Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы:

— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей".

Также есть другое правило, согласно которому при разрыве незаконченной прямой речи словами автора первая часть прямой речи оканчивается запятой или многоточием, слова автора пишутся с маленькой буквы, далее после них ставится запятая и следующая часть разорванной прямой речи начинается также с маленькой буквы.

Пример из Розенталя:
"Если на месте «разрыва» прямой речи словами автора не должно было бы быть никакого знака препинания или должна была бы стоять запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие либо тире, то слова автора выделяются с обеих сторон запятыми и тире, после которых первое слово пишется со строчной буквы:

«Мы решили, — продолжал заседатель, — с вашего дозволения остаться здесь ночевать».

Что делать с пунктуацией в случае совмещения этих двух правил? Например, в таком предложении:

"Я говорил (?) — Он встал и прошёлся по комнате (?) — что это плохая идея".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что можно использовать такой **вариант** оформления:

***— Я говорил**... — Он встал и прошёлся по комнате. — ...**что это плохая идея.***

**Пояснение**

Правило Розенталя. **[§ 52. Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160)**

4. Если одна реплика **«разрывается»** другой, а затем следует продолжение первой реплики, то после первой ее части и перед началом второй ставится многоточие:

*— Я просил…*

*— Ничего вы не просили.*

— *…хотя бы минуту внимания.*

В нашем случае ситуация похожая, только дословное высказывание прерывается не другой репликой, а описанием **действий** персонажа.